# How to white list iOS app for playback of my own restricted videos

Tags: ios, youtube-api

We own the YouTube account we're trying to play content from, but playback within our iOS app using the YouTube Helper is being restricted: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#best_practices

[image: iOS playback error]

Is this perhaps because of the anonymity of the web view created by the helper?

Can I configure the helper or account differently to unblock the content? I guess I could serve a web view from a whitelisted host, essentially bypassing/re-writing the YouTube helper, but that would not be ideal - extra http request etc..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my current understanding and work around.

**The Problem**

Any kind of access restriction on a channel (whitelist/blacklist etc.) requires that the parent of the iframe be served from a real host. The iOS YouTube Helper Library manually creates a webview into which the iframe is loaded, and so the channel block playback because it isn't possible to restrict playback within the parent (anonymous webview).

This is easily verified for a given channel by pasting an embed for a video from the channel into a simple local HTML page, and loading it into your browser. Playback will be blocked.

**The Solution**

So, we need a web page that uses the iFrame API served from a not-blacklisted/whitelisted (depending on your channel access control) host. I took the [HTML template from the youtube helper library](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Assets/YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html), and parameterized the URL to fill in the params to the template initialization:

```
new YT.Player('player', %@);
```

So now rather than loading data from a template HTML string in the helper, I now load a request:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:req];
```

The final gotcha is that the "handleHttpNavigationToUrl" condition in the following block was causing Safari to open on page load, so comment out or handle that better:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  if ([request.URL.scheme isEqual:@"ytplayer"]) {
    [self notifyDelegateOfYouTubeCallbackUrl:request.URL];
    return NO;
  } else if ([request.URL.scheme isEqual: @"http"] || [request.URL.scheme isEqual:@"https"]) {
    return [self handleHttpNavigationToUrl:request.URL];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

**The New Problem**

This work around adds one more delay into the flow of loading a video for the user. The new HTTP request to serve the initial page joins the existing steps of:

1. Load YouTube iFrame API JS
2. Load iFrame of player
3. Begin stream of video initialized into player

All of this, rather than just initializing a native player with a stream URL. Not a great user experience for sure.

I plan on working around it by preloading the page, API and iframe ready for initialization with a video ID on user request.

Answer (score 1):

Mine problem was that when I clicked on the play button it showed me an error. I was trying to load youtube video.

> This video contains content from <..channelname..>. It is restricted from
>   playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube.

The solution which I used was this

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
    @"origin" : @"http://www.youtube.com",
    ...any other variables
};
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:videoId playerVars:playerVars];
```

simply add origin variable in the playerVar and you are good to go.

Hope this help someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Helper library is basically a wrapper around the iFrame API. You could repurpose the helper, or use the iFrame API straight for your whitelisted host.

Comment: I can see that pasting an embed from this channel into a simple local *.html files results in the same error, so it does indeed appear that as a result of the channel needing black listing, anonymous container pages (or "about:blank" as used in the helper) are also blacklisted/excluded. Is there a channel setting to enable playback within the helper without serving from an actual host (extra HTTP request) and rewriting the JS/iOS bridge?

Comment: I very much doubt it, so I worked around it as show in the accepted answer. It would be valuable to make a note of this in the limitations section of the helper guide: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#best_practices